# How do I move the oddhead and evenhead by 0.5 inch?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm working on fixing a document that used to require page number on top right and from about 1 inch. Currently, it was defined as:

```
\def\@@evenhead{\hfil\textrm{\thepage}}
```

The new requirements need the page number up by 0.5 inch. I have tried to set the `\hoffset` to -0.5inch, or `\topmargin` to -0.5 inch. Never of them worked. They will move the entire body of text up by 0.5 inch.

My question is: can I move the page number up by revising this evenhead definition?  I really don't want to use fancyhdr package.

Thank you!

Comment: WELCOME! Please, can you add a MWE?

Comment: (1) welcome (2) you probably want to post some code others can test. As your question is now noone will have any chance to help as they know nothing at all about your document

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The code is too complex... I need to greatly simply it.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moving just the header page number up, raise it:

```
\def\@@evenhead{\hfil\raisebox{.5in}[0pt][0pt]{\thepage}}
```

The `[0pt][0pt]` optional addition removes any vertical height/depth adjustments that may result from raising the page number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No. I don't want to move the entire body of text. I just wanted to move the page # up. However, the page number is currently defined as \hfill{\thepage} on top of the page. I think it was treated as body of text. So, moving  TopMargin or voffset does not seem to help.   Can you put a \vspace{-0.5} and \hfill{} together to better position \thepage?

Comment: @LonnieLee: If you just want to move the page number up, `\raisebox` should suffice. See my updated answer.